# Where are the scripts located in Blender in mac osx10?

Tags: macos, blender

I normally wouldn't post this in stack overflow, but I can't find out where the scripts folder is. I want to write a custom exporter for blender and I need to see the wavefront .obj export script and base it off of that. I have looked in my blender.app and searched for .blender but I never find anything.

Answer (score 5):

The `.blender` folder name is old and was used back before version 2.50, since 2.50 the scripts folder can be found in  `<version>/scripts` where `<version>` matches the version of blender, inside `scripts` you will find the `addons` folder that you are looking for.

In windows and *nix the `<version>` folder can be found in the same folder as blender, in OSX however it gets moved into the Resources folder, leading you to `blender.app/Contents/Resources/<version>/scripts`

You also have the option of browsing the source tree online. You can find blender's source repositories at [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/) with the wavefront exporter located within [Blender Addons](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/), you can also find some other addons within [Blender Addons Contrib](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/)

Also [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask blender specific questions including python coding.